# Asyncio + aiohttp - redis Pub/Sub and websocket read/write in single handler

Tags: python, redis, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm currently playing with [aiohttp](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.org/) to see how it will perform as a server application for mobile app with websocket connection.

Here is simple "Hello world" example ([as gist here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2b0432082e0171683beb)):

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from aiohttp import web


class WebsocketEchoHandler:

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def __call__(self, request):
        ws = web.WebSocketResponse()
        ws.start(request)

        print('Connection opened')
        try:
            while True:
                msg = yield from ws.receive()
                ws.send_str(msg.data + '/answer')
        except:
            pass
        finally:
            print('Connection closed')
        return ws


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = aiohttp.web.Application()
    app.router.add_route('GET', '/ws', WebsocketEchoHandler())

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    handler = app.make_handler()

    f = loop.create_server(
        handler,
        '127.0.0.1',
        8080,
    )

    srv = loop.run_until_complete(f)
    print("Server started at {sock[0]}:{sock[1]}".format(
        sock=srv.sockets[0].getsockname()
    ))
    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        loop.run_until_complete(handler.finish_connections(1.0))
        srv.close()
        loop.run_until_complete(srv.wait_closed())
        loop.run_until_complete(app.finish())
    loop.close()
```

#### The problem

Now I would like to use structure described below (node server = python aiohttp). To be more specific, use [Redis Pub/Sub](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub) mechanism with [asyncio-redis](https://github.com/jonathanslenders/asyncio-redis) to read and write both to websocket connection and Redis in my *WebsocketEchoHandler*.

*WebsocketEchoHandler* is a dead simple loop so I'm not sure how should this be done. Using [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org) and [brükva](https://github.com/evilkost/brukva) I would just use callbacks.

[image: http://goldfirestudios.com/blog/136/Horizontally-Scaling-Node.js-and-WebSockets-with-Redis]

#### Extra (offtopic perhaps) question

Since I'm using [Redis](http://redis.io/) already, which of two approaches should I take:

1. Like in "classic" web app, have a controller/view for everything, use [Redis](http://redis.io/) just for messaging etc.
2. Web app should be just a layer between client and [Redis](http://redis.io/) used also as task queue (simplest [Python RQ](http://python-rq.org/)). Every request should be delegated to workers.

#### EDIT

Image from http://goldfirestudios.com/blog/136/Horizontally-Scaling-Node.js-and-WebSockets-with-Redis

#### EDIT 2

It seems that I need to clarify.

- **Websocket-only handler is shown above**
- **Redis Pub/Sub handler might look like that:**

  ```
  class WebsocketEchoHandler:

      @asyncio.coroutine
      def __call__(self, request):
          ws = web.WebSocketResponse()
          ws.start(request)

          connection = yield from asyncio_redis.Connection.create(host='127.0.0.1', port=6379)
          subscriber = yield from connection.start_subscribe()
          yield from subscriber.subscribe(['ch1', 'ch2'])

          print('Connection opened')
          try:
              while True:
                  msg = yield from subscriber.next_published()
                  ws.send_str(msg.value + '/answer')
          except:
              pass
          finally:
              print('Connection closed')
          return ws
  ```

  This handler just subscribes to Redis channel *ch1* and *ch2* and sends every received message from those channels to websocket.
- **I want to have this handler:**

  ```
  class WebsocketEchoHandler:

      @asyncio.coroutine
      def __call__(self, request):
          ws = web.WebSocketResponse()
          ws.start(request)

          connection = yield from asyncio_redis.Connection.create(host='127.0.0.1', port=6379)
          subscriber = yield from connection.start_subscribe()
          yield from subscriber.subscribe(['ch1', 'ch2'])

          print('Connection opened')
          try:
              while True:
                  # If message recived from redis OR from websocket
                  msg_ws = yield from ws.receive()
                  msg_redis = yield from subscriber.next_published()
                  if msg_ws:
                      # push to redis / do something else
                      self.on_msg_from_ws(msg_ws)
                  if msg_redis:
                      self.on_msg_from_redis(msg_redis)
          except:
              pass
          finally:
              print('Connection closed')
          return ws
  ```

  But following code is always called sequentially so reading from websocket blocks reading from Redis:

  ```
  msg_ws = yield from ws.receive()
  msg_redis = yield from subscriber.next_published()
  ```

I want reading to be done *on event* where *event* is message received from one of two sources.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. That is your problem exactly?

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov Updated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should use two `while` loops - one that handles messages from the websocket, and one that handles messages from redis. Your main handler can just kick off two coroutines, one handling each loop, and then wait on *both* of them:

```
class WebsocketEchoHandler:
    @asyncio.coroutine
    def __call__(self, request):
        ws = web.WebSocketResponse()
        ws.start(request)

        connection = yield from asyncio_redis.Connection.create(host='127.0.0.1', port=6379)
        subscriber = yield from connection.start_subscribe()
        yield from subscriber.subscribe(['ch1', 'ch2'])

        print('Connection opened')
        try:
            # Kick off both coroutines in parallel, and then block
            # until both are completed.
            yield from asyncio.gather(self.handle_ws(ws), self.handle_redis(subscriber))
        except Exception as e:  # Don't do except: pass
            import traceback
            traceback.print_exc()
        finally:
            print('Connection closed')
        return ws

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def handle_ws(self, ws):
        while True:
            msg_ws = yield from ws.receive()
            if msg_ws:
                self.on_msg_from_ws(msg_ws)

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def handle_redis(self, subscriber):
        while True:
            msg_redis = yield from subscriber.next_published()
            if msg_redis:
                self.on_msg_from_redis(msg_redis)
```

This way you can read from any of the two potential sources without having to care about the other.

Comment: Thank you @dano, this is exactly what I wanted. I've been playing with _asyncio.gather_ but placing it inside a loop and other mess...

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I have no idea how to send msg from server side to client by websocket until I see here. I can 'publish ch1 <msg>' in redis-cli and recevied it in client side. Good Q&A.

Comment: @dano I don't see two **loops** here. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @EugeneNaydenov both `handle_redis` and `handle_ws` contain `while True:` loops.

Comment: Thanks @dano. Got you. I've just messed with asyncio's loop. :)

Comment: @EugeneNaydenov Ah, I see your confusion. I've edited my answer to disambiguate.

Answer (score 2):

recent we can use async await in python 3.5 and above..

```
async def task1(ws):
    async for msg in ws:
        if msg.type == WSMsgType.TEXT:
            data = msg.data
            print(data)
            if data:
                await ws.send_str('pong')
## ch is a redis channel
async def task2(ch):
    async for msg in ch1.iter(encoding="utf-8", decoder=json.loads):
        print("receving", msg)
        user_token = msg['token']
        if user_token in r_cons.keys():
            _ws = r_cons[user_token]
            await  _ws.send_json(msg)

coroutines = list()
coroutines.append(task1(ws))
coroutines.append(task2(ch1))

await asyncio.gather(*coroutines)
```

this is what I do.when the websockets need to wait message from mutli source.

main point here is using asyncio.gather to run two corotine together like 
@dano mentioned.